# I want to convert the text file data to JSON using Jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, scripting, jq

I have the date in the file which looks like

```
test,test
test1,test1
```

I want to convert it into like:

```
{"test":"test","test1":"test1"}
```

I have tried jq for this purpose `jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")'`

But its oupting in the format `["test,test","test1,test1",""]`

Comment: anyone please help? :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jq 1.5 has `inputs`, which allows a simple and efficient solution:

```
 jq -R -n -c '[inputs|split(",")|{(.[0]):.[1]}] | add' input.txt
```

Important: don't forget the `-n` (`--null-input`) option, otherwise you'll lose the first line.

### Alternative

If your jq does not have `inputs`, then it's time to upgrade if at all possible.  Otherwise:

```
jq -R -s '
  split("\n")
  | map(if index(",") then split(",")|{(.[0]):.[1]}
        else empty end)
  | add' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. that's pretty much the output I want. Is it possible that the output will be in a single line? like this `{"test":"test","test1":"test1"}`

Answer (score 1):

As @peak indicates, use the `inputs` with the `split` function. But to merge the key/values into one single object, use the [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) method:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs|split(",")| {(.[0]): .[1]}] | reduce .[] as $obj ({}; . + $obj) ' input.csv
```

The `reduce` method reduces each item in the array into a single item. In this case, we indicate that each item should be assigned to the `$obj` variable, and that we start out with the empty `{}` object. The second argument to the `reduce` method indicates how to "reduce" things down to a single item. In this case, we are adding/merging the `$obj` we assigned with the `{}` object we started out with and then returning the resulting object to be used in the next iteration. After all the iterations have completed, the final item (in this case, the combined object) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is possible to achieve with just standar unix shell utilities (assuming your input in `file.txt`):

```
bash $ echo { \"$(<file.txt sed 's/,/":"/g' | paste -s -d, - | sed 's/,/","/g')\" } 
{ "test":"test","test1":"test1" }
bash $
```

- resulting output is a valid json